# Oracle extractvalue to select xml data into diferent Path

Tags: xml, oracle

How can i select xml data using oracle extractvalue function, when i do have two diferent kinds of paths to address information ?

For year and brand i can recover the information using :

```
extractvalue(xmltype(x.xml, 0), '//Vehicle/Year') as VEC_YEAR,
```

But for address i have the error message: ORA31011 fail parsing xml and ORA19202 and LPX00601: Invalid token : //Brand/Info/Data/Address

```
SELECT 
      extractvalue(xmltype(x.xml, 0), '//Vehicle/Year') as VEC_YEAR,
      extractvalue(xmltype(x.xml, 0), '//Vehicle/Brand') as VEC_BRAND,
    CASE 
      WHEN extractvalue(xmltype(x.xml, 0), '//Brand/Info/Data/Address') IS NOT NULL THEN extractvalue(xmltype(x.xml, 0), '//Brand/Info/Data/Address')
      WHEN extractvalue(xmltype(x.xml, 0), '//Brand/MainInfo/Info/Data/Address') IS NOT NULL THEN  extractvalue(xmltype(x.xml, 0), '//Brand/MainInfo/Info/Data/Address') 
    END as Adress,
    FROM xml_table x
```

These are the XML i have to query :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<VehicleValidation xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Validation Id="Validation">
        <Vehicle>
            <Year>2017</Year>
            <Brand>One car brand</Brand>
        </Vehicle>

        <Brand>
            <Info>
                <Data>
                    <Address>
                    One car brand Address
                    </Address>
                <Data>
            </Info>
        </Brand>
    </Validation>
</VehicleValidation>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<VehicleValidation xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Validation Id="Validation">
        <Vehicle>
            <Year>2017</Year>
            <Brand>One car brand</Brand>
        </Vehicle>

        <Brand>

            <MainInfo>

                <Info>
                    <Data>
                        <Address>
                            One car brand Address
                        </Address>
                    <Data>
                </Info>

            </MainInfo>
        </Brand>
    </Validation>
</VehicleValidation>
```

Comment: **Please** show a valid XML data set that you are referencing.

Comment: Just add then to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example.. Notes. Please try not to use extractValue(). It's been deprecated. You should use the SQL/XML operators defined by the XML Standard. To extract relational rows from an XML document XMLTABLE should be the operator of choice..

```
SQL> with MY_TABLE as
  2  (
  3    select XMLTYPE(
  4  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  5  <VehicleValidation xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  6      <Validation Id="Validation">
  7          <Vehicle>
  8              <Year>2017</Year>
  9              <Brand>One car brand</Brand>
 10          </Vehicle>
 11          <Brand>
 12              <Info>
 13                  <Data>
 14                      <Address>
 15                      One car brand Address
 16                      </Address>
 17                  </Data>
 18              </Info>
 19          </Brand>
 20      </Validation>
 21  </VehicleValidation>') as XMLDOC
 22      from DUAL
 23     union all
 24    select XMLTYPE(
 25  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 26  <VehicleValidation xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 27      <Validation Id="Validation">
 28          <Vehicle>
 29              <Year>2017</Year>
 30              <Brand>One car brand</Brand>
 31          </Vehicle>
 32          <Brand>
 33              <MainInfo>
 34                  <Info>
 35                      <Data>
 36                          <Address>
 37                              One car brand Address
 38                          </Address>
 39                      </Data>
 40                  </Info>
 41              </MainInfo>
 42          </Brand>
 43      </Validation>
 44  </VehicleValidation>') as XMLDOC
 45    from dual
 46  )
 47  select Brand, Address
 48    from MY_TABLE,
 49         XMLTABLE(
 50           '/VehicleValidation/Validation'
 51           passing XMLDOC
 52           COLUMNS
 53             BRAND   VARCHAR2(32)   PATH 'Vehicle/Brand',
 54             ADDRESS VARCHAR2(64) PATH 'Brand//Info/Data/Address'
 55         )
 56  /

BRAND                            ADDRESS
-------------------------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------
One car brand
                                                     One car brand Address


One car brand
                                                             One car brand Address
```

Answer (score 1):

How about taking any Info/Data/Address below a Brand?
i.e. using XPath //Brand//Info/Data/Address instead of //Brand/Info/Data/Address and //Brand/MainInfo/Info/Data/Address
https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev

If you need to be exact, try using existsnode instead of extractvalue in your when conditions
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10790/xdb04cre.htm#i1032763

By the way, the Data tag is not closed properly in the xml posted.